# Join the same descriptor variable for 2 different variables

Tags: sql, ssms-2016

I'm sure this is very basic, but I'm having a hard time and am not having luck searching for similar questions that have already been answered.  I'm joining up tables and need to join and return the same variable for two different variables.  That's probably not a great explanation - here's an example:

*Table1*
RequestingStaffMemberID
DocumentNo

*Table2*
CollectingStaffMemberID
DocumentNo

*Table3*
StaffMemberID
StaffMemberName

I want to join up table 1&3 and table 2&3 on StaffMemberID so that I can return:
StaffMemberName(as StaffMemberID=RequestingStaffMemberID)
and StaffMemberName(as StaffMemberID=CollectingStaffMemberID)

How do I cast/convert/declare something to do this so that I'm not asking it to return StaffMemberName twice? Right now I just have it return the CollectingStaffMemberID and index/match it offline in Excel because I was in a pinch, but I want to learn how to do this correctly in SQL.

```
SELECT a.DocumentNo, c.StaffMemberName, b.CollectingStaffMemberID

FROM Table1 as a

left join Table2 as b on
a.DocumentNo=b.DocumentNo

left join Table3 as c on 
a.RequestingStaffMemberID=c.StaffMemberID

GROUP BY a.DocumentNo, c.StaffMemberName, b.CollectingStaffMemberID
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why do a GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: @jarlh because I'm very new and have just been learning as I go editing inherited code and didn't know you don't need it! haha  So thank you for teaching me something today!

Comment: You can join Table3 again. Join first for `RequestingStaffMemberID` and a second time for `CollectingStaffMemberID`

Comment: What do you mean by "not asking it to return StaffMemberName twice"? two columns or duplicated rows? Please provide smaple data

Comment: @HoneyBadger I understand that in concept, but I'm not sure how to do it, because I can't ask it to return StaffMemberName twice for different variables without renaming it somehow, right?

Comment: @PeterHe  I want it to return StaffMemberName as 2 columns, 1 representing the join of StaffMemberID=RequestingStaffMemberID and 1 as StaffMemberID=CollectingStaffMemberID, but I don't know how to do that because I'd be asking it to ```SELECT StaffMemberName, StaffMemberName```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT  Requests.DocumentNo
,       Staff_Req.StaffMemberName AS RequestStaffMemberName
,       Staff_Col.StaffMemberName AS CollectionStaffMemberName
FROM    Table1 as Requests
LEFT JOIN Table2 as Collections 
        ON Requests.DocumentNo = Collections.DocumentNo
LEFT JOIN Table3 as Staff_Req
        ON Staff_Req.StaffMemberID = Requests.RequestingStaffMemberID
LEFT JOIN Table3 as Staff_Col
        ON Staff_Col.StaffMemberID = Collections.CollectingStaffMemberID
```

I also gave your tables better aliases, so you know what's what (although I'm sure your actual tables have more descriptive names).

Comment: thank you! I just couldn't quite figure that piece out - still learning!

Comment: It's sometimes difficult to search for missing knowledge. You need to know what words to use as keywords. That's why we're here.